# Possible JSON to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'm a little bit fresh to the concept of `JSON`s, so bear with me here.

I have a method that returns the following long and complicated string:

```
[{\"identifierType\":\".Identifier\",\"title\":\"Test\",\"typeName\":\"Application1\",\"key\":\"1\",\"internalId\":1},{\"identifierType\":\".Identifier\",\"title\":\"Test2\",\"typeName\":\"Application2\",\"key\":\"2\",\"internalId\":15},{\"identifierType\":\".Identifier\",\"title\":\"Test3\",\"typeName\":\"Application3\",\"key\":\"3\",\"internalId\":1124},{\"identifierType\":\".Identifier\",\"title\":\"Test4\",\"typeName\":\"Application4\",\"key\":\"4\",\"internalId\":2241}]
```

She's a long and ugly eyesore, but it's what I've got to work with.

After a little bit of googling, I discovered that this was a `JSON`-string, and that she could be mapped to a `Dictionary` in `C#`.

Now, after a little more googling, I arrived at this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(s);
```

In this case `s` is my long and ugly string.

The problem is that this throws an error when running.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Now me being green as a cabbage in `JSON`, I was rendered dumbstruck by this.

Is my not-so-beautiful `s` not the `JSON`-string I thought she was?

If she is, shouldn't this then in theory work?

I also foresee a problem with the fact that there appears to be more than one object in `s`. Won't that cause trouble when I'm trying to map it to a `Dictionary`?

Do I have to map `s` to multiple `Dictionary`s?

Please advise.

Comment: did you try `List<Dictionary<string, string>> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(s);`? Because your JSON text starts with `[`

Comment: are those escaped quotes actually in the json?

Comment: Your json doesn't seem to be valid , test it here, it gives invalid json http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate

Comment: It's valid, it's just escaped as a c# string literal. Replace all `\"`s with `"`s :)

Comment: Try to get rid the square brackets at the start and end of the string because it makes the array from your string, however deserializer does not recognize it properly. You have 4 items in your source string separated by coma, so to deserialize it properly you would need to create List od Dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json is an array of  let's say `YourJsonObject`, so you could deserialize it into a `List<YourJsonObject>`.

The  http://json2csharp.com site comes in handy in these scenairos, so by pasting your json there it emits the following class:

```
public class YourJsonObject
{
    public string identifierType { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string typeName { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public int internalId { get; set; }
}
```

and

`var list = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<YourJsonOject>>(s);`

gets you the thing you want. If you'd really wanted to you could deserialize it into a List of Dictionaries as a commenter above me suggested, but as it contains an integer too it's probably better this way.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed! And what a handy tool that http://json2csharp.com is. +1 and best answer for you, friend!

Answer (score 2):

First, let's beautify your JSON. I used [JsonEditorOnline](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)'s round-tripping function, that website is pretty useful for one-off investigations into JSON data:

```js
[
  {
    "identifierType": ".Identifier",
    "title": "Test",
    "typeName": "Application1",
    "key": "1",
    "internalId": 1
  },
  {
    "identifierType": ".Identifier",
    "title": "Test2",
    "typeName": "Application2",
    "key": "2",
    "internalId": 15
  },
  {
    "identifierType": ".Identifier",
    "title": "Test3",
    "typeName": "Application3",
    "key": "3",
    "internalId": 1124
  },
  {
    "identifierType": ".Identifier",
    "title": "Test4",
    "typeName": "Application4",
    "key": "4",
    "internalId": 2241
  }
]
```

JSON has the nice property that if you know the basics, it's really easy to read by humans. The brackets `[ ]` indicate an array, and the braces `{ }` are for objects.
In this case, you have an array of objects, whose properties are `identifierType`, `title`, `typeName`, `key` and `internalId`.

The easiest way to convert this to data you can work with in C# is to create a class that matches this structure:

```
public class MyItem // pick a better name, of course
{
    [JsonProperty("identifierType")]
    public string IdentifierType { get; set; }

    // add the other properties in the same fashion
}
```

Then, you can convert that JSON to your data structure:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItem>>( yourJsonString );
```

Comment: A massive +1 for a great answer. I found the one bellow slightly easier to understand, but if I could give you +10, I would!

Answer (score -1):

Your 's' is not a json.

Its Json Array of Json Objects.
In C# terms say list of dictionary.

For eg-

JsonArray:

[{"d":1},{"y":1},{"z":3}]

Solution could be parse into json array and then foreach value create a dictionary.

Json Object:

{"a":1,"b":2}